# how to paginate gridview in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I am having grid in my website. But Resulted rows are more than 20,000. My web site got slower. I want to divide rows into several pages.

In one page requested rows are 500 to 1000.

Plz Note :- Changes want in published website. The Source Code got deleted.

Comment: try
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/410733/custom-paging-with-asp-net-gridview

Comment: what you have tried???

Comment: fooTable is an excellent client-side solution for this (no need to faff about with creating separate pages from the server-side) - http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/ . But really a quick Google search should have turned up plenty of possible solutions. Question shows a distinct lack of research effort IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public string strConnection = "Data Source=.; uid=sa; pwd=sa;database=test;";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }
    protected void BindData()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserDetails", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }
```

You can set the page size and count in gridview properties

Comment: Thank u very much buddy

Answer (score 1):

Do pagination using jquery since it will be client side and fast.

```
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/show-and-paging-in-asp-net-gridview-using-jquery/
```

Comment: will it affect to other jquery functions?

Comment: It will not affect other jquery function but if there will be any error in syntax then your any jquery code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

> I am having **grid** in my website. But Resulted rows are more than
>   20,000. My web site got slower. I want to divide rows into several
>   pages.
>   In one page requested rows are 500 to 1000.

Assuming your grid is a GridView:

**.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="YourIDHere" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="YourIDHere_PageIndexChanging"
    PageSize="500">
    <Columns>
        <!-- Your BoundFields or other data goes here -->
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="10" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void YourIDHere_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    YourIDHere.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    YourIDHere.DataBind();
}
```